# How can I raise a Frame from another class?

Tags: python, tkinter

I want to raise a Frame from another class, but I'm getting an error(frame is not defined).

Does anyone can help me with this issue?

Thanks

```
import tkinter as tk
import ttkbootstrap as ttk
from gui_elements import ButtonFrame, EntryFrame, TreeviewFrame, FrameFrame, NotebookFrame, ThemeSelector, Page


class App(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.geometry("1000x800")

        self.frame_main = FrameFrame(self)
        self.frame_main.pack(side=tk.LEFT,expand=True, fill=tk.BOTH)
     

        self.theme = ThemeSelector(self.frame_main)
        self.theme.pack()

        self.entry_frame = EntryFrame(self.frame_main)
        self.entry_frame2 = EntryFrame(self.frame_main)
        self.entry_frame.pack()
        self.entry_frame2.pack()

        self.notebook_frame = NotebookFrame(self.frame_main)
        self.notebook_frame.pack()

        self.treeview_frame = TreeviewFrame(self.frame_main)
        self.treeview_frame.pack()

        self.btn_raise = ttk.Button(self.frame_main, text="Raise", command=lambda:Page.raise_frame(self.container_menu))
        self.btn_raise.pack()

class PageOne(Page):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
       Page.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)

       self.container_menu = FrameFrame(self)
       self.container_menu.pack(expand=True, fill=tk.BOTH)

       f1 = FrameFrame(self.container_menu)
       f2 = FrameFrame(self.container_menu)
       f3 = FrameFrame(self.container_menu)
       f4 = FrameFrame(self.container_menu)

       for frame in (f1, f2, f3, f4):
         #frame.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky='news')
           frame.place(relwidth=1, relheight=1)
        
       #Page1
       btn1 = ButtonFrame(f1, text="Next Page", command=lambda:self.raise_frame(f2))
       btn1.pack()

       #Page2
       btn2 = ButtonFrame(f2, text="Previous Page", command=lambda:self.raise_frame(f1))
       btn2.pack()

       self.raise_frame(f1)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = App()
    app.mainloop()
```

The basic setup of my code.

I defined in another python file all my buttons and frames.

In my main file I only define the objects and pack all widgets on the screen.

I tried to fix this bug, but I´m struggle, because I have no clue how to get access to the frame container_menu from the class PageOne. My goal is to raise a frame which stores all widget from the class PageOne.

Comment: I don't understand the question.  You are already accessing `self.container_menu` inside the class `PageOne`.  Where are you getting that error?

Comment: And to piggyback off of @TimRoberts, *what* error are you getting specifically? Please include the traceback with your question

Comment: Sorry I am new to stack overflow and I have to work on my description skills. Now I mean frame not window. When pressing the button raise, I want to raise the frame self.container_menu. When I am running the code I am getting the error AttributeError: '_tkinter.tkapp' object has no attribute 'container_menu'

Comment: First you need to have some testable code. It would be best to provide a simple small example we could run. Second its a little unclear as to your need. You can raise a frame but it might be better to manage what is in a frame instead of stacking them.

Comment: It should be possible to create a [mcve] that does not use the `gui_elements` and `ttkbootstrap` modules, since the problem doesn't seem to be directly related to either of those.

Comment: In order to call `container_menu`, you need to have an object of type `PageOne`.  I don't see you creating that object anywhere.  It is that OBJECT you would use in your lambda.

Answer (score 0):

maybe you mean?

```
from ttkbootstrap import Frame, Entry, Treeview, Frame, Notebook
```

read about themes in tkinter
https://docs.python.org/3/library/tkinter.ttk.html

and about tkinter-page
https://pypi.org/project/tkinter-page/

maybe you mean to open a window instead of raise a frame?